# Win7 /Ubuntu 14.04 on 1 drive; Win XP on 1 drive -- Boots into XP

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I'm so close to finally having Ubuntu up and running.
The first time, I let boot-repair do its thing automatically http://paste.ubuntu.com/7804480/ then couldn't boot into anything.

I had a fiddle with it and this is what I have: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7804855

3 drives:
Win XP on 1 (C:)
Win7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on 1 (G:/H:)
Data on 1 (F:)

I've put each one first in the boot sequence.
C: XP boots OK.
G:/H: gives the error 'No such partition'.
F: no such device (followed by a long alphanumeric string: c190ef54-81...)

I'm close, I can feel it! :)

Thanks for any help.

[UPDATE]
After a few more failed attempts -plus my XP system disc refusing to help me out by restoring the MBR- I think the best thing is to put Ubuntu on its own drive (cheers from the crowd!) and Win7 can move in with XP. I'd put 7 on its own but I don't see a way to power a fourth drive without replacing my aging motherboard.